# A closer look on the derivation of the susceptibility in the Ising-Model

Tags: differentiation, ising-model, partition-function

The susceptibility $\chi$ can be defined as

$$ \chi = \frac{\partial \langle M \rangle}{\partial H}, \tag{1}$$

where $\langle M \rangle$ is defined as the average magnetization and thus can be written as

$$\langle M \rangle = \frac{1}{Z} \sum M \exp\left(-\beta\left(\sum_{\langle i,j \rangle} J_{ij}\sigma_i \sigma_j + H\sum_i \sigma_i\right)\right),\tag{2}$$

with $Z = \exp(-\beta \mathcal{H})$ being the partition function.

If I put the definiton (2) for the average magnetization in the derivation (1) I should get to the equation

$$\chi = \beta\left(\left\langle M^2\right\rangle-\left\langle M\right\rangle_{}^2\right). \tag{3}$$

In [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/362353/246867) that motivates my question the writer also gives a more compact version of $\langle M \rangle$ as
$$\langle M \rangle = -\frac{1}{\beta} \frac{\partial}{\partial H}\ln(Z).\tag{4}$$

So if I put this into the derivation I could simplify the exp-function inside the logarithm
$$-\frac{1}{\beta}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial H^2} \ln(Z) = -\frac{1}{\beta}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial H^2} (-\beta \mathcal{H}), \tag{5}$$

where $\mathcal{H}$ is the Hamiltonian of the Ising-Model
$$\mathcal{H} = -J \sum_{\langle i,j \rangle} \sigma_i \sigma_j - H \sum_j \sigma_j \tag{6}$$

---

Coming now to my questions:

1. I get a completely wrong result if I do the step in equation (5). Why is this wrong?
2. How do I obtain $\chi = -\beta\left(\left\langle\sum_{i,j}\sigma_{i}\sigma_{j}\right\rangle- \left\langle \sum_{i}\sigma_{i} \right\rangle \left\langle\sum_{j}\sigma_{j}\right\rangle\right)$ from $\chi = \frac{\partial \langle M \rangle}{\partial H}$?

I computed the derivation in equation (1) three or four times and always get an expression different from equation (3).

Comment: Well, $Z\neq \exp(-\beta\mathcal{H})$. With the correct formula, you'll get the desired result with a simple computation...

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is the error, that $Z = \sum \exp(-\beta H)$ and so it can't be simplified with the logarithm?

Comment: Yes. Just differentiate now.

Comment: Thank you. I also found another mistake I did with the indices. So this plus your correction and I also get the stated result!